# What happened when Horace Slughorn took Felix Felicis?

Tags: harry-potter

Horace Slughorn told his students that he took the potion *Felix Felicis* twice - once when he was twenty-four years old, and again when he was fifty-seven. Is there any source why he took the potion, or what happened on these days?

It might have something to do with a woman but that is pure speculation as I don't know if he was in a relationship.

Comment: There hasn't been any substantial evidence to say anything about his romantic life.

Comment: It's not at all an answer, but I'd suggest that the fifty-seven one was when he realized he shouldn't have told Tom Riddle about horcruxes and hoped nobody would find out he did that... if so, it worked for quite a while. (the taking of the potion would have been quite some time after the telling)